# resx file lost reference in solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution where my resource file has suddenly stopped being referenced. The resource is included in my solution and it is generating the class file, which contains all the string references, etc. I can also add strings to the file and these are reflected in the generated class too.

However, when I try to reference in a Razor file I get the following error;

> The type or namespace name 'Comments' does not exist in the namespace 'Common' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Per other Stack questions, I have set 'CustomTool' property to be 'ResXFileCodeGenerator' but this doesn't seem to have made a difference?

[image: common.resx properties]
resx properties
[image: common.designer.cs]
generated class
[image: razor error view]
razor error
I am currently using Visual Studio 2017 community 15.4.0 for info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Pulic` as Access Modifier for your resource file.
In your View you have to use the full namespace to your class:

```
BridgeDirect.Common.Comments
```

If you want to include your namespace for all views you can add it to your Web.config:

```
  <system.web>
...
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="BridgeDirect" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>    
  </system.web>
```

Comment: the namespace is already added in the views web.config. its odd as i have tried a @using BridgeDirect in the razor view too. For some reason the Common class is not appearring through intellisense either? could it be a .csproj manipulation needed here?

Comment: Did you try to replace `internal class Common` with `public class Common` (Access Modifier in Resx View)?

Comment: Sorry i didnt do that, yes this fixed it. Thanks for the help.